# 2D Water top surface profile

Tags: opengl, directx, unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I am trying to create the effect of the water surface thickness with a vertex-fragment shader.

I am in a 3D game environment but It's a scroll view so a "2D" view.
[Here](http://rotatingcanvas.com/fragment-shader-to-simulate-water-surface-in-libgdx/) is a good tutorial of creating such effect in real 2D using fragment shader.
But this can't be used in my case I think.
For the moment I have only a plane were I apply refraction.

[image: refraction]

And I want to apply the water thickness effect. But I don't know how to do it.
I am not trying to create some water deformation/displacement using vertex for the moment, this is not the point.

I don't know if it's possible with a simple quad maybe should I use an object like this.

[image: system]

Here are some examples.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 4]
[image: rayman]

Thanks a lot !

[**EDIT**] Added Rayman water effect to have a better reference of the effect.

Comment: Why do you think that this effect is created "on a simple quad"?

Comment: I am sorry, I misspoke, what I mean is that I already made a shader with refraction and it's applied on a quad. And I wanted to know how can I perform this effect under this condition.

Comment: None of those pictures show any [*refraction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction).

Comment: I know, I am not talking about a refraction effect. I've already done this. Here I am just talking about the thickness of the top water surface. For now I juste have the straight border of my quad. Do you know what I mean ? And I don't how to create this thickness effect.

Comment: @MaT: A water surface has no "thickness" (at least no visible one). What you refer to as "thickness" is in fact the result of total internal refraction at the meniscus (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meniscus) between water and container/glass. And you can't do it with just a quad. You must render a complex water surface to get this effect.

Comment: @datenwolf: I totally agree with you concerning the effect. In reality there is no thickness. But the aim is to copy this effect, not simulate. I am searching for a small trick to copy this effect I don't want any real physical shader.

Comment: @MaT: Well, you could use a 1D texture to define a transition gradient and modulate its texture coordinate using some animated perlin noise or similar. It's not exactly what you need, but this might give you the idea: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/texture_distortion_glsl/texture_distortion_glsl.c

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks, I thing it's the only solution I have.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to create **2D** Water effect with a vertex-fragment shader on a simple quad.

Your first misconception is thinking in 2D. What you see in your right picture is the interaction of light with a 2 surface in a 3D space. A simple quad will not suffice.

For water you need some surface displacement. You can either simulate this by solving some wave equation. Or you're using a fourier transform based approach. I suggest the second. Next you render your scene "regular" for everything above the water, then "murky and refracted" for everything below the water line. Render both to textures.

Then You render the water surface. When looking at the *Air→Water Interface* (i.e. from above) use a Fresnel reflection term, i.e. mix between top reflection and see through depending on the angle of incidence, and for a too small angle emulate Brewster reflection. For the *Water→Air Interface* (i.e. from below) you do similar, only you don't need the Fresnel term, but only the Brewster term, to account for total internal reflection.

Since you do all mixing in the fragment shader, you don't need blending, hence no need to sort drawing operations for the water depth.

Yes, rendering water is not trivial.